# magento bae url not working after dulicate site

Tags: .htaccess, magento

1. I have a site http://www.gingerlily.fr
2. i copy those file and create sub directory on root called **test**  and uploaded the file to  it
3. duplicated db and apply update for all base url db and other configurations. (http://www.gingerlily.fr/test)
4. **but the problem is when i access http://www.gingerlily.fr/test 
   site i always show root urls and other js and images loads from root magento installation**. i try a day for thi but no luck.

can anyone help me for this **something wrong with httacess file or any other wrong with this** ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your http://www.gingerlily.fr/. Correct me if i am wrong your trying to duplicate your site to test directory. But in magento your can't copy and duplicate site like PHP /Html     here your files of magento site need to be first install and you can replace your module and theme files.

Comment: n luck, i deleted th var folder and local.xml file then install magento as a new instance but still link an images loading from old site